# W3C validator error: Attribute placeholder is only allowed when the input type is

Tags: html, placeholder, w3c-validation, html-input

Given the HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <form> 
      <input type="email" placeholder="E-Mail"/>
    </form>  
  </body>
</html>
```

the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org) (v1.3) gives the following error message:

> Line 8, Column 48: Attribute `placeholder` is only allowed when the input type is e-mail, number, password, search, tel, text, or url.

Why?

Comment: There is some documentation http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/Using-HTML5-for-Automatic-Placeholders-in-Email-Forms--With-No-JavaScript-3921981.htm#fbid=Kh714s2DboL. Everything seems to be alright in your code.

Comment: @nicael: Would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: @Alexey: Thanks for the link. I just wonder why the validator flags this HTML as incorrect.

Comment: I have tried your code in Chrome, Firefox and IE. And the placeholder is there (in the input field) in all three cases. Maybe there is some bug in the validator?

Comment: @Alexey Many thanks for your effort! In fact it seems to be a bug in the validator as it is apparently fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the validator.

Both validators, http://validator.w3.org/ and http://validator.w3.org/nu/, report that the `placeholder` attribute is "only allowed when the input type is `e-mail` […]".
However, the HTML5 input type is called [`email`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29), not `e-mail` (which both validators correctly recognize if `type="e-mail"` is used instead).

Without looking at the code, I guess that when `placeholder` is used, they check for `e-mail` instead of `email`. It works as expected with all other allowed input types.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be fixed now in both  http://validator.w3.org/ and http://validator.w3.org/nu/.

Comment: @user2286693: Yes, right. The [fix is mentioned on the mailing list](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2015Mar/0013.html) (and [also in another thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2015Mar/0015.html)).